# How to catch hover for different level div?

Tags: jquery, css, html, hover

I have two div element which are not nested but they are seem overlapped.

How can I catch the hover function for first div when mouse enter the second div?

(When mouse is on orange area, I expect to mouse is also on gray area.)

Please check the  [http://jsfiddle.net/tZFuX/2/][1]

Thanks!

Comment: How you are making those 2 divs are unique? By Id? try checking event.target.SomeProperty=="" . Property can be id, tagName etc in hover event and do

Comment: (When mouse is on orange area, I expect to mouse is also on gray area.)

Please check the http://jsfiddle.net/tZFuX/2/

Comment: Why don't you wrap them with another `div` and bind the hover events on it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/tZFuX/4/)

```
$('.div1').on({
   mouseenter: function(){
      alert('mouse entered at div1');
   }
});

$('.div2').on({
   mouseenter: function(){
     alert('mouse entered at div2');
     $('.div1').trigger('mouseenter');
   }
});
```

### Edit: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZFuX/5/)

The alerts will work in this way, nevertheless you can tryout with addClass:

```
 $('.div2').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
       $('.div1').addClass('active');
    }
 });

 $('.div1').on({
    mouseout: function () {
       $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
 });
```

Comment: It should not leave first area, when entering second area. I mean, triggering mouseEnter again not useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using pure CSS, you can use [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events), as long as you're happy that the result [will only work in WebKit & Firefox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events), and also removes all mouse interactivity from the element it's applied to (no clicks, text selection, etc).

You apply this with as follows:

```
.div2 {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/barney/Mcxf2/

So it becomes pretty easy to tie that into a scripted solution. For a fully scripted solution without the pointer-events dependency, you would have to bind a `mousemove` event to the whole document (or window, or body — or any element you know will visually contain both elements), and then test properties. This is pretty expensive as whatever code you use to test the cursor position against the element's will execute continuously during mouse movement — the jQuery site offers a [basic tutorial on this](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position):

http://jsfiddle.net/barney/AmQhs/

The code is necessarily a bit more elaborate, but you get the gist.